New Shirt Designs for a New Name
I previously tried to make a design to put on shirts. But now we have a new name, so that means new shirt designs!
Currently, I've converged on the idea:

Something flashy on the front
URL on the back

However, I'm still trying to figure out what flashy thing to put on the front.

After my graphic design friends screamed in horror at my previous design, here is my more minimalist approach.
Front:

I'm also open to the alternative slogan "Researchers finding answers together"
Back:


Still not a fan of the font, but your graphic design friend had good inputs I see. :)

@StevenJeuris remind me, did you have suggestions for better fonts?

Here's my current best attempt:

Any opinions?
